# Codeigniter routing error involving underscore

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm having a problem with Codeigniter routing which involves underscores in controller class names.  Here's my problem and how to replicate it.

1) clone or download Codeigniter and save in a folder in htdocs called 'test'

```
git clone https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter.git
```

2) create the following controller and save as C_track.php:

```
class C_track extends CI_Controller {
  public function index(){ echo "index done"; }
  public function demo(){ echo "demo done"; }
}
```

3) add the following route:

```
$route['track']= 'C_track';
```

4) Set 'base_url' within config.php correctly (for my setup, it's...):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/test/';
```

At this point, if I go to: http://localhost:8888/test/index.php/track/
I see: index done

but, if I go to: http://localhost:8888/test/index.php/track/demo
I get a 404 error.

I am expecting to see: demo done

Ok, now things get strange

5)create the following controller and save as Track.php:

```
class Track extends CI_Controller {
  public function index(){ echo "index DONE!!!"; }
  public function demo(){ echo "demo DONE!!!"; }
}
```

6) Do not add a new route!

At this point, if I go to: http://localhost:8888/test/index.php/track/
I see: index done

but, if I go to: http://localhost:8888/test/index.php/track/demo
I see: demo DONE!!!

This is not what I am expecting.  For some reason, Codeigniter is running the demo function within Track.php, even though the file is not even listed in routes.php.  I'm guessing that the underscore is the problem.  because:

7) change routes.php:

```
$route['track']= 'Track';
```

Now, if I go to: http://localhost:8888/test/index.php/track/
I see: index DONE!!!

but, if I go to: http://localhost:8888/test/index.php/track/demo
I see: demo DONE!!!

Which is exactly what I expect to see!!

How can I fix this?  I would really like to find a way to solve this problem so that underscores work as expected, because my naming scheme is based heavily on underscores in file names & class names.

Comment: create route with 
`$route['track\(:any)']= 'C_track'; `
to access all method inside one controller

for more details [show this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['track']= 'C_track';
```

In a route, the array key contains the URI to be matched, while the array value contains the destination it should be re-routed to. In the above code, *track* is matched in the URI as final segment i.e. URI is delimited with **/** and broken into segments[image: segment_description].

For handling http://localhost:8888/test/index.php/track/demo use

```
$route['track/(:any)']= 'C_track';
```

The above will match 1 segment after *track* with any type of value and redirect it to the controller 'C_track'.
Furthermore, the reason behind */track/demo* working if you change the controller as **Track.php** is because when you rename the controller to *Track.php*, the URI matches with this controller by default without the need of adding a custom route in **Routes.php**.